# NDSolveValue not working correctly

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

So I am trying to get a good representation of the 2d heat equation with mathematica but it does not seem to work correctly:

```
heqn = D[u[t,x,y], t] -Laplacian[u[t,x,y], {x,y}]

shape = Rectangle[{0,0},{10,10}]

ic = u[0,x,y] == x+y

bc = NeumannValue[0, True]

sol = NDSolveValue[{heqn == bc, ic}, u, {t, 0, 300}, {x,y}\[Element]shape]

Manipulate[Plot3D[sol[t,x,y], {x, 0,10},{y,0,10},ColorFunction->Function[{x,y,z},Hue[z]]], {t,0,300}]
```

Initial Condition :

[image]

The expected result is equilibrium after some time but instead the heat is just transferring over and causing really weird things to happen in the plot:

[image]

Comment: Try fixing your plot range like so `Manipulate[
 Plot3D[sol[t, x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]], 
  PlotRange -> {0, 20}], {t, 0, 300}]`.  The z plot range is so small that your are just observing small numerical error.

Comment: no the roughness is not the problem the problem is that from the initial condition the flow just reversed instead of reaching equilibrium

Comment: @TimLaska Never Mind this solved it